# How to get @value property from applicationContext

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

I am trying to get class fields with @value annotation and then fill it by applicationContext.
I am using spring framework.

myClzz.java:

```
  @Value("#{T(java.time.Duration).parse('${interval:PT12H}')}")
  private Duration interval;
```

myService.java:

```
Field field = FieldUtils.getFieldsWithAnnotation(myClzz.getClass(), Value.class);

//get "#{T(java.time.Duration).parse('${interval:PT12H}')}" from the field:
String value = field.getDeclaredAnnotations()....


String result = applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty(value)
```

application.properties:

```
interval=PT12H
```

But getProperty does not work with that "#{T(java.time.Duration).parse('${interval:PT12H}')}" string.

Is there any way to make it work without parsing?

Comment: Could you provide the property file?
Is your property name "intervel:PT12H"?

Comment: I have just tried this on my test app and it works perfectly.
What kind of error do you have?

Comment: yes my property is interval=PT12H. applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("interval") works for me, But applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("#{T(java.time.Duration).parse('${interval:PT12H}')}") does not work.

Comment: Do you have an error/exception/stacktrace ?

Comment: @Value("#{T(java.time.Duration).parse('${intervel:PT12H}')}")
 private Duration interval;

Works like a charm in my test project :)

Comment: no errors, simply return null. I succeed to solve it with:   applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBeanProperties(clzz, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, true);

Comment: I would suggest the following trick just to check: add String filed and mark with @Value("interval"). It will give us more info where is the issue.